# Show table in CMS Block

Tags: database, cms, static-block

Does anyone have a script to pull a table from an external database to load into a CMS block? I have a database separate from Magento (a client list) that needs to populate a CMS block.

Answer (score 1):

Loading data from any database will require a custom module with custom block. To be able to add it to a CMS block, you will have to write a [widget](/questions/tagged/widget).

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to do this would be to either create a custom module or widget.

But you could also include a custom template file and load the table data

```
{{block type="core/template" template="path/to/templatefile.phtml"}}
```

Comment: Okay. I was thinking of going the route of just creating the custom template. It seems like creating a module would be too much work. Are there any drawbacks of the custom template vs. the module?

Comment: Just MVC principle